# Returning a random number from a range of numbers using C

Tags: c, random

An array of integers of size n. I need to generate a random permutation of the array, given a function rand_n() that returns an integer between 1 and n, both inclusive, with equal probability. I know about the random function in java but I want to implement it using C.

Comment: C has `rand`. However you probably want to look up a shuffling algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand why google was not used for this.

Comment: But using the rand function is not my motive.Is there any way where I can implement my own algorithm

Comment: You mean you want to implement your own pseudo random number generator? You didn't say that. You probably just want to google 'PRNG algorithms' then.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) is wat you search for.

Comment: +1 for the link. Nah, it was for mentioning the Mersenne twister. <g>

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int randint(int min, int max) 
{ 
    if (min>max) 
    { 
        return max+(int)((min-max+1)*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return min+(int)((max-min+1)*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own as follows:

```
int rand_n( int N )
{
  return ( rand() % N ) + 1;
}
```

`rand()` is declared in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: But i dont want to use the rand function

Comment: Why don't you want to use rand? Read [pseudo-random number generators](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) on Wikipedia, the external links section at the bottom has links to several implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the question is not about writing a PRNG, it's about using a predefined rand_n function to write an algorithm to shuffle the array. Writing a PRNG is not trivial, I doubt they'd ask you that in an interview. But a shuffling algorithm is a different story. Here's one, in pseudocode, off the top of my head:

Iteration 1:

- Fill an array with the numbers from 1 to N, let's call it positions
- i = rand_n(N);
- shuffled[0] = toShuffle[ positions[i] ];
- Delete i from positions and resize it (now it has N-1 elements)

Iteration 2:

- i = rand_n(N-1)
- shuffled[1] = toShuffle[ positions[i] ];
- Delete i from positions and resize it (now it has N-2 elements)

...Catch my drift?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) shuffle.  This produces a random permutation of an array by randomly swapping elements (thus using a simple `rand_n` type function to select the elements.)